# SeedStack , proxy configuration while doing rest api call during feign client?

Tags: seedstack

I was doing one sipmle rest api call using feign client but upable to call rest api as it was not passing because of proxy.
I tried setting up System.setProperties(props); props contain proxy url, and port no. but still it is unable to do rest call.
Can you please tell me how to configure proxy in seedstack using feign client.

Answer (score 1):

By default, SeedStack will automatically configure a JVM-wide proxy using the (relatively) standard `http_proxy`, `https_proxy` and `no_proxy` environment variables.

- The `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` variables should have the following format:

  ```
  http[s]://[user:password@]proxy.example.com:8080
  ```
- The `no_proxy` variable is a comma-separated list of exclusion patterns:

  ```
  *.domain.com, *.other.com
  ```

If you want to specify proxy configuration manually, you can do so in the `application.yaml` file:

```
proxy:
  mode: ENABLED|DISABLED|AUTO
  httpProxy: ...
  httpsProxy: ...
  noProxy: ...
```

- The `mode` property determines if the proxy should be always enabled, always disabled or automatic based on the environment variables (the default).
- Other properties should have the same format as their environment variable counterparts.

When a proxy is configured (automatically or manually) a log will be printed at application startup.